# how do I save a stringarray assigned in string.xml?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-savedstate

This is the Stringarray from my xml file declared:

```
Resources res = getResources();

    final String[] list = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

The onSaveInstanceState Code looks like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    outState.putStringArrayList("list",  R.array.myArray); 

}
/* Gives me this error :Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'int', required: 
 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>'. . . */
```

What is missing , what is wrong , I dont understand, I tried many different conjunctions of how to call myArray, didnt work, if you need additional information let me know.

[Android Studio is trying to help me but I dont know how to write this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3F1a.png)

Comment: The error is pretty clear -- you need to pass an `ArrayList<String>` and not an int as the second argument.

Comment: Yea , but I don understand how thats an int in the first place, can u give me a sample ..?

Comment: The `R...` constants are just `int`s, a numeric key to the actual resource data

Comment: How is the syntax supposed to look ? It seems like I cant call my Array outside the onCreate method .. ?

Comment: The first code snippet already shows how to retrieve the resource as `String[]`. Just convert this to `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>` (read the docs of `ArrayList`).

Comment: Yea it even says @Nullable ArrayList<String> value , (added in my Question)

and I guess in the java docs it wont be written any different, I just cant really make a picture out of it, I need like a real world sample to get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your array into list and then can pass it as the second argument like this:

```
    List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(list);
    outState.putStringArrayList("list", (ArrayList<String>) arrayList);
```

Comment: = Arrays.asList(list);    
instead of "list" im supposed to type in myArray right, in any case if I type in my StringArray  or list I get the same error : Cannot resolve symbol "..".

Comment: Like, it does show my other strings as option in the autocomplete window, but not my stringarray ..

Comment: You can write like this = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray))

Comment: This will work in most Java implementations but there is no guarantee that the cast will succeed.

Comment: So we can also do it in another way -> ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);
then add this "myList" as the second argument

Comment: Abhishek Sharma, can u give me an snippet how that would look with the String Array "myArray" ? 
Meaning the way when u said "So we can also do it in another way ->"

Comment: List<String> aList = Arrays.asList(list); and put this aList in ArrayList object like this :- ArrayList<String> myList = new Arraylist<>(aList); and pass this myList in the second argument of outState.putStringArrayList();